# Existence of Subshell structures for molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, orbitals

For Hydrogen atom, we could explicitly solve Schrodinger's Equation, a partial differential equation. Using reparametrization, we arrive at series solution using Frobenius method. From this we see quantum numbers arise which lead to atomic subshell structures of s,p,d orbitals and so on. But to me, how quantum numbers arise seem to be an artifact of symmetry. Specifically, the potential term only contains radial variable which allows for separation of variables, which simplifies the PDE to set of ODEs. But for complicated molecules, we will see potential terms that contain mixed variables in which case PDE is no longer separable since potential terms due to nuclei is no longer only radially dependent. So how do we know that for molecules, the subshell structure is still preserved? Has this been proven? It seems rather odd that we take generalization of subshell structure for complicated molecules as granted when we don't have the same type of symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are asking if atoms change their original nuclear subshell structure/configuration after they bond to form molecules? There does not appear to be any reason *a priori* why this should be the case.

Given that bonding and therefore molecular structure is dictated by electrons, nuclear structure and electron configuration can be treated as two separate phenomena.

In the [Born-Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation) the electron wave functions and nuclear wave functions are separate (not that this method explicitly looks at nuclear shell structure, but instead the nuclear wave function as a whole). Therefore the Hamiltonian *can* be separated into electronic and nuclear parts, simplifying calculations.

There may be additional interactions between the electrons of each atom and the nuclei after the bonding, but these interactions will very likely not affect the shell structure of the individual atomic nuclei.
Also note that nucleon-nucleon interactions are *significantly* stronger than electromagnetic interactions.

Comment: If we take the water molecule for example, we will have V(r(theta, phi)) for central potential term in Schrodinger equation for the electron since potential experienced by an electron due to 3 nuclei is no longer spherically symmetric. This is no longer separable and no series solution exists. Therefore we don't know  that subshell structure for electrons is the same as that for the separable case of single atom. So I'm asking why we assume electron subshell structure is retained for each atoms in a molecule formed through a bond.